# input of LSTM network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm having trouble with preparing input data for LSTM on Keras.
my data shape is:

- number of files: 276
- dimensions of files: 213*276

each file belongs to one month from 1993-2015.

I want to prepare this data to be fed into LSTM on Keras. i want to predict the last 12 months(last year)

how can i prepare the data? should i make a big column and concatenate all years?

And what shape should Y_train be in?

here is the details from original paper:

https://filebin.net/5gmsupuz2nqtb8qb/11dd.png?t=1j844rml

https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to an LSTM model should be three dimensional, in the format [samples, timestep, features]. In this case it suggests that your input could be something like [276, 213, 276]: this is speculation however, and will depend on how the data that you are using was organised. Check the appropriate length timestep for your specific problem (but typically something in the range 100-250), research papers are helpful here.

Your input shape for y will depend on what you want to train the model to do. If this is a classification task, you'll likely have a single label. But, if it was a forecasting task then you'll have a variable length sequence depending on how far in advance you want the model to predict.